# How to handle "504 gateway timeout" in Opencart module

Tags: php, api, opencart, crm

I wrote my module by send Opencart's orders to my CRM. But in this case I set event by post.add but is not OK because when client refresh their shopping cart, my order is still adding in CRM and by this reason i've got duplicate same order. I decided set post.order.history.add event but in this case I've got 504 gateway timeout. What I can do in this situation?
Note, my CRM and shop on same VPS.

This is my module:

```
public function check_phone($number)
{
    //bla bla bla
    $retunr $number;
}

public function on_order_add($order_id)
{
    $this->load->model('checkout/order');
    $value = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

    //prepare loggin
    $url_login = "*********/login/enter/";
    $login = array();
    $login["username"] = "username";
    $login["password"] = "password";
    $login["remember"] = "on";
    $login["act"] = "act";
    //login
    $curl = curl_init($url_login);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($login));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); //saved cookies
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,

        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
    $response = (curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);

    //prepare order
    $orders = array();
    $order_id = $order_id;
    $url = "******/orders/api/";


    $orders["act"] = "add_packaging_order";
    //ORDER
    $orders["id_user_add"] = 21; //system by default
    $orders["date_calendar"] = date("Y-m-d");
    $orders["timepicker"] = date("H:i:s");

    if ($value["payment_code"] == "cod" || $value["payment_code"] == "cheque")
        $orders["inlineRadioOptions"] = "cash"; // НАЛ ИЛИ БЕЗНАЛ
    else
        $orders["inlineRadioOptions"] = "cashless";

    if (stristr($value["email"], 'localhost') !== false)
        $value["email"] = " Не указано\n";


    $orders["status"] = 1;
    //ORDER_END

    //auto
    if ($value["shipping_code"] == "flat.flat") {
        $orders["show_next_auto"] = "on";
        $orders["autoname"] = "Для доставки упаковки за 99грн";
        $orders["summary_auto"] = 1;
        $orders["price_auto_agree"] = 0;
    }
    if ($value["shipping_code"] == "free.free") {
        $orders["show_next_auto"] = "on";
        $orders["autoname"] = "Для бесплатной доставки упаковки";
        $orders["summary_auto"] = 1;
        $orders["price_auto_agree"] = 0;
    }
    //end auto


    //start clients
    $orders["name_clients[]"] = $value["lastname"] . " " . $value["firstname"];
    $orders["sendsms"] = 0;
    $orders["signature"] = "=======";
    $orders["number_order"] = $order_id;
    $orders["phones[]"] = $this->check_phone($value["telephone"]);


    //end clients
    $custom_fields = "";
    //address
    if (isset($value["custom_field"]))
        $custom_data = ($value["custom_field"]);
    if (isset($custom_data[17]))
        $orders["company_name"] = $custom_data[17];

    if (isset($custom_data[4]))
        $orders["addres[]"] = $custom_data[4];
    else
        if (isset($custom_data[8]) || isset($custom_data[9]) || isset($custom_data[12])) {
            $orders["addres[]"] = $custom_data[8] . ", " . $custom_data[9] . "  склад№" . $custom_data[12];
        } else
            $orders["addres[]"] = "Не указан";

    if (isset($custom_data[18]))
        $custom_fields .= "\nЕГРПОУ:" . $custom_data[18] . "\n";
    if (isset($custom_data[19]))
        $custom_fields .= "\nНомер свидетельства плательщика НДС :" . $custom_data[19] .
            "\n";
    $orders["addres_counter"] = "2";
    if (isset($custom_data[16]))
        if ($custom_data[16] == 26)
            $custom_fields .= "\nЮридическое лицо\n";
        else
            $custom_fields .= "\Физическое лицо\n";
    ///end address

    $orders["commentary_total_order"] .= "Номер заказа в магазине№" . $order_id . "\n " .
        $value["comment"] . "\n " . "EMAIL:" . $value["email"] . "\n Оплата: " . $value["payment_method"] .
        "\n Доставка: " . $value["shipping_method"]; // КОММЕНТАРИИ

    //default
    $addr_query_string = "&num_build[]=&num_office_flat[]=";


    //product

    $this->load->model('account/order');
    $products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($order_id);
    $orders["show_next_pack"] = "on";

    $q = "";
    foreach ($products as $value => $key) {
        $q .= "&pack[]=" . urlencode($key["name"] . " (" . $key["sku"] . ")");
        $q .= "&num_pack[]=" . urlencode($key["quantity"]);
        $q .= "&unit[]=" . urlencode("1");
        $q .= "&price_pack[]=" . urlencode($key["price"]);

    }


    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($orders).$q.$addr_query_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); //saved cookies
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
    $response = (curl_exec($curl));  
    curl_close($curl);


}
```

}